# Nested Quantifier Practice Question: Some student has never been asked a question by a faculty member.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

So I was practicing nested quantifiers for class, and I came to an answer which I think is right, but the book gave something slightly different. For starters, the context of the question is this:

11. Let $S(x)$ be the predicate “$x$ is a student”, $F(x)$ be the predicate “$x$ is a faculty member”, and $A(x, y)$ be the predicate “$x$ has asked $y$ a question”, where the domain consists of all people associated with your school.

h) Some student has never been asked a question by a faculty member.

My answer to this = $∃x∃y(S(x) ∧ F(y) → ¬A(y, x))$

The books answer = $∃x(S(x) ∧ ∀y(F(y) → ¬A(y, x)))$

Does the $∀y$ have to be in the middle of the expression to be correct? Does the book show it this way because it's clearer where the nesting occurs?

Comment: Statement says that there exists a student such that none of the faculty members has ever asked him/her a question.  
So, existence of only the student is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the ∀y have to be in the middle of the expression ?

Not necessarily; see [Prenex normal form equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction) : $(\forall y\phi )\land \psi$  is equivalent to $\forall y(\phi \land \psi)$.

Thus, $∃x[S(x) ∧ ∀y(F(y) → ¬A(y, x))]$ and $∃x∀y[S(x) ∧ (F(y) → ¬A(y, x))]$ are equivalent.

Having said, that, the book's transaltion sounds more similar to natural language :

> "There is someone ($∃x$) that is a student ($S(x)$) and ..."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I hadn't learned about prenex normal form equivalences yet, but that makes more sense now! I do have one additional question, what do you mean by "y is not free in S(x)"? Are you saying that y isn't within the scope of students?

Comment: @NickSabia - to say that $y$ is not *free* in a formula $\varphi$ means that : either (i) $y$ does not occur in the formula, or (ii) that every occurrence of $y$ is in the *scope* of a quantifier $\exists y$ or $\forall y$. Due to the fact that $S(x)$ is an atomic formula with only a unary *predicate* symbol, case (i) applies : there is no $y$ occurring in it.